# When the algebraic degree of the ring containing the GCD is not obvious

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Most of the time we subconsciously determine the ring a GCD computation is to take place in purely from context. For example, $\gcd(28, 63)$ is clearly a GCD computation in $\textbf Z$, while $\gcd(28, 9 + 3 \sqrt 2)$ takes place in $\textbf Z[\sqrt 2]$. I think the answer of the former pair would be the same in the latter ring, right?

What about something like $\gcd(21 - 21 \sqrt 3, 9 + 3 \sqrt 2)$? It seems to me the answer is neither in $\textbf Z[\sqrt 2]$ nor $\textbf Z[\sqrt 3]$. I'm guessing the GCD would be in the ring of integers of $\textbf Q(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)$, which is of degree $4$.

In general, if the GCD can't be resolved in $\textbf Z$ nor in either of the rings of least algebraic degree containing the two operands, would the ring of least algebraic degree containing the GCD be of algebraic degree equal to the product of the algebraic degrees of the two operands?

Comment: ... I think you have some misconceptions about GCDs. GCDs are computed within a particular ring. Both elements you take the GCD of have to be in that ring. You can't take the GCD of things not in the same ring. Perhaps you mean given two algebraic integers, what is the degree of the field generated by both of them? Maybe? Idk

Comment: For what it's worth, I think $\gcd(21 - 21 \sqrt 3, 9 + 3 \sqrt 2) = 1$. If I'm right, there's no need to go to quartal rings, at least for that example.

Comment: @RobertSoupe In the ring of algebraic integers of any number field containing both those numbers they are surely both divisible by any prime ideal lying above the rational prime $3$! So I fail to see why you would claim the gcd to be equal to one?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen For perhaps the same reason Mersenne made those claims about certain numbers of the form $2^n - 1$.